# Issue with custom errors configuration in my Sitecore 10.1 instance

Tags: configuration, error-handling

I am facing an issue whereby custom errors are not redirecting to error page configured.

I have custom errors remote only set in the `web.config` as below:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="/ErrorPage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

And an `ErrorPage.aspx` within the root of the application. It appears that this is not being caught though.

Is there something different within Sitecore 10 that prevents this to previous versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using the `redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"` attribute uses `Server.Transfer` behind the scenes so relative routes will not work with the older `.net MVC 4.8 framework`. This is not a Sitecore specific issue.

I managed to get it to trigger by removing `redirectMode` attribute and adding
`responseMode="file"`, this allowed me to serve a static html page.

Transform snippet is as follows...

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace" defaultRedirect="/ErrorPage.html" >
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/ErrorPage.html" responseMode="File"/>
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks correct, I have pulled the config below from a working Sitecore 10.1 solution.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/500" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/500" />
</customErrors>
```

Is the config you have posted from the transform file? Or is that the resulting content from the web.config? If so, please try removing the
`xdt:Transform="Replace"` as this should not be present.

Comment: Will /ErrorPage.aspx be served with Server error 500? Should that not be a static html file instead?

Comment: @JuliusA I tried with .html, this current project is a migration from 7.2, it is using an aspx file there so I have dropped it into the new solution.

Comment: @Julius A - In our situation we redirect 500 error to a published Sitecore page (/500). The controller rendering served on that page gives friendly response to the error. I believe the .aspx should work just as well.

Comment: If there is Server error, server won't serve the .aspx, hence falling back to static html

Answer (score 0):

Recently I did the similar configuration for 404 error page redirection by using below setting in 10.1 version:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
<remove statusCode="404" />
<error statusCode="404" path="404.html or 404.aspx or 404.htm" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

I hope the same works for you by just **changing the status code**.

Refer to this link for more details on [custom error display from Sitecore item and File](https://sitecoreseries.blogspot.com/2022/09/displaying-custom-404-error-page-for.html).

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at using httpErrors instead and report back

Comment: This solution will not work for 500 errors as per Microsoft documentation

Comment: If there is Server error, server won't serve the .aspx, hence falling back to static html in such scenarios.